# System.Array Error for an ASP.NET application that sends email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendmail

I am getting a set of errors in this application I created that should be sending email. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
Below is the set of errors:

Error   1   'SmtpServer' is not a member of 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient'.       96  9   SendingEmail

Error   2   'To' is not a member of 'System.Array'.                             100 9   SendingEmail

Error   3   'From' is not a member of 'System.Array'.                           104 9   SendingEmail

Error   4   'isBodyHtml' is not a member of 'System.Array'.                     109 13  SendingEmail

Error   5   Name 'MailFormat' is not declared.                                  109 34  SendingEmail

Error   6   'BodyFormat' is not a member of 'System.Array'.
111 13  SendingEmail

Error   7   Name 'MailFormat' is not declared.                                  111 34  SendingEmail

Error   8   'Subject' is not a member of 'System.Array'.                        120 9   SendingEmail

Error   9   'Attachments' is not a member of 'System.Array'.                    125 13  SendingEmail

Error   10  'Body' is not a member of 'System.Array'.                           129 9   SendingEmail

Error   11  Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Net.Mail.MailMessage' cannot be converted to 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'.132 18  SendingEmail

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class SendEmail
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    ' Variable which will send the mail
    Dim obj As  _
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

'Variable to store the attachments 
Dim Attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment

'Variable to create the message to send
Dim MailMsg As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

 Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Dim Counter As Integer

    'Validate the data
    If txtSMTPServer.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the SMTP server info ...!!!", _
        MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtFrom.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the From email address ...!!!", _
               MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtTo.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the Recipient email address ...!!!", _
                 MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtSubject.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the Email subject ...!!!", _
                 MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Set the properties
    'Assign the SMTP server
    obj.SmtpServer = txtSMTPServer.Text

    'Multiple recepients can be specified using ; as the delimeter
    'Address of the recipient
    MailMsg.To = txtTo.Text

    'Your From Address
    'You can also use a custom header Reply-To for a different replyto address
    MailMsg.From = "\" & txtFromDisplayName.Text & "\ <" & txtFrom.Text & ">"


    'Specify the body format
    If chkFormat.Checked = True Then
        MailMsg.isBodyHtml = MailFormat.Html 'Send the mail in HTML Format
    Else
        MailMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
    End If

    'If you want you can add a reply to header 
    'Mailmsg.Headers.Add("Reply-To", "testmail@mail.com")
    'custom headersare added like this
    'Mailmsg.Headers.Add("Manoj", "TestHeader")

    'Mail Subject
    MailMsg.Subject = txtSubject.Text
    'Attach the files one by one
    For Counter = 0 To lstAttachment.Items.Count - 1
        Attachment = New Net.Mail.Attachment(lstAttachment.Items(Counter))
        'Add it to the mail message
        MailMsg.Attachments.Add(Attachment)
    Next

    'Mail Body
    MailMsg.Body = txtMessage.Text

    'Call the send method to send the mail
    obj.Send(MailMsg)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have declared `MailMsg` as an _array_.  An array does not have a `From` or `To` property.  Change the declaration to this (note parentheses have been removed): `Dim MailMsg As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`

Comment: @Chris, thank for your response. I change that declaration as instructed, now I am get the following errors:Error 1 SmtpServer' is not a member of 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient'. 95; Error 2 Property 'To' is 'ReadOnly'. 99; Error 3 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress'. 103; Error 4 Name 'MailFormat' is not declared. 108 ;Error 5 'BodyFormat' is not a member of 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'. 110                                                  Error 6 Name 'MailFormat' is not declared. 110

Answer (score 0):

This line is one issue: Dim MailMsg As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
I changed in below to read

```
Dim MailMsg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
```

In the first declaration having the parentheses declares an array of MailMsg. Adding the New makes a valid constructor.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class SendEmail
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    ' Variable which will send the mail
    Dim obj As  _
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

'Variable to store the attachments 
Dim Attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment

'Variable to create the message to send
Dim MailMsg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

 Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Dim Counter As Integer

    'Validate the data
    If txtSMTPServer.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the SMTP server info ...!!!", _
        MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtFrom.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the From email address ...!!!", _
               MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtTo.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the Recipient email address ...!!!", _
                 MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtSubject.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter the Email subject ...!!!", _
                 MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send Email")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Set the properties
    'Assign the SMTP server
    obj.SmtpServer = txtSMTPServer.Text

    'Multiple recepients can be specified using ; as the delimeter
    'Address of the recipient
    MailMsg.To = txtTo.Text

    'Your From Address
    'You can also use a custom header Reply-To for a different replyto address
    MailMsg.From = "\" & txtFromDisplayName.Text & "\ <" & txtFrom.Text & ">"


    'Specify the body format
    If chkFormat.Checked = True Then
        MailMsg.isBodyHtml = MailFormat.Html 'Send the mail in HTML Format
    Else
        MailMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
    End If

    'If you want you can add a reply to header 
    'Mailmsg.Headers.Add("Reply-To", "testmail@mail.com")
    'custom headersare added like this
    'Mailmsg.Headers.Add("Manoj", "TestHeader")

    'Mail Subject
    MailMsg.Subject = txtSubject.Text
    'Attach the files one by one
    For Counter = 0 To lstAttachment.Items.Count - 1
        Attachment = New Net.Mail.Attachment(lstAttachment.Items(Counter))
        'Add it to the mail message
        MailMsg.Attachments.Add(Attachment)
    Next

    'Mail Body
    MailMsg.Body = txtMessage.Text

    'Call the send method to send the mail
    obj.Send(MailMsg)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what did you change?  Code only answers are not high quality.

Comment: @Jeremy, I do not see any change in this answer. Could you clarify? Thanks.